# Make v-card stretch to the bottom of the parent component

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js, css-grid

I have v-card that is inside of v-navigation-drawer:

```
 <v-navigation-drawer
      dark
      src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/bg-2.jpg"
      width="100%"
      permanent
      class="rounded"
    >
      <v-btn>Test</v-btn> <v-btn>Test</v-btn>
      <v-card-text>A Text</v-card-text>
      <v-card class="blue elevation-7" width="240">
        <v-card-text>
          <div class="font-weight-bold ml-8 mb-2">Today</div>

          <v-timeline align-top dense>
            <v-timeline-item
              v-for="message in messages"
              :key="message.time"
              :color="message.color"
              small
            >
              <div>
                <div class="font-weight-normal">
                  <strong>{{ message.from }}</strong> @{{ message.time }}
                </div>
                <div>{{ message.message }}</div>
              </div>
            </v-timeline-item>
          </v-timeline>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

How can I make it to stretch/fill in to the bottom of the parent component so that parent component remains same height as the rest of the grid?

Here is helper picutre of what im trying to achieve (marked by black lines I tried to have the nav-drawer have the same height as the content on the right (3 cards) also the card inside the nav-drawer should fill it to the bottom but not past it.

[image]

Here is the minimal reproducible example where you can see yourself that its not working:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-barchart-forked-c08hr?file=/src/components/dashboard/MiniMenu.vue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, Let me just repeat what I understood:

- you want to make the navigation drawer height to be equal to the content
- you want the card inside the navigation drawer to fill the height of the navigation drawer

to get your first point done all you have to do is to remove the value of `min-height` property (by default its `100vh`):

```
.v-application--wrap {
  min-height: unset;
}
```

In this way, the application height will fit your content.

now to the second problem, in order to make the card fill the rest of the navigation drawer, you'll need some help from flexbox [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979148/1892335)

```
.v-navigation-drawer__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.v-card.blue {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

I've tried my solution on your example and here's the complete code of the vue file

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/bg-2.jpg"
    width="240"
    permanent
    floating
    class="rounded flex-shrink-0 mr-3"
  >
    <div>
      <v-btn>Test</v-btn> <v-btn>Test</v-btn>
    </div>
    <v-card-text>A Text</v-card-text>
    <v-card class="blue elevation-7" width="240">
      <v-card-text>
        <div class="font-weight-bold ml-8 mb-2">Today</div>

        <v-timeline align-top dense>
          <v-timeline-item
            v-for="message in messages"
            :key="message.time"
            :color="message.color"
            small
          >
            <div>
              <div class="font-weight-normal">
                <strong>{{ message.from }}</strong> @{{ message.time }}
              </div>
              <div>{{ message.message }}</div>
            </div>
          </v-timeline-item>
        </v-timeline>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    messages: [
      {
        from: "You",
        message: `Sure, I'll see you later.`,
        time: "10:42am",
        color: "deep-purple lighten-1",
      },
      {
        from: "John Doe",
        message: "Yeah, sure. Does 1:00pm work?",
        time: "10:37am",
        color: "green",
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>

<style>
.v-application--wrap {
  min-height: unset;
}

.v-navigation-drawer__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.v-card.blue {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
</style>
```

and here's a screenshot of the result [image]

### EDIT

I've noticed from the comments that you also want to get rid of the space (padding) inside the navigation drawer. To do this you simply have to add `px-0` and `py-0` classes to your navigation drawer.

```
class="rounded flex-shrink-0 mr-3 px-0 py-0"
```

**ps**: notice that I had to wrap the two `v-btn`s with so that they don't get affected by the `display: flex` property of their parent.

here's an updated picture of the final output [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-barchart-forked-exuis?file=/src/components/dashboard/MiniMenu.vue)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you should be able to achieve it with CSS only.
I'm not sure if this is what you want?
[image]

If this suits your needs, than just set one of the parent `div`s to `display: block;`

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-barchart-forked-z9gmt?file=/src/components/dashboard/MiniMenu.vue)

```css
.v-application--wrap {
    display: block;
}
```

---

The other solution. I could think of, would be to stretch the SalesCards like this

[image]

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-barchart-forked-7iep9?file=/src/components/ExampleComponent.vue)

---

### EDIT

For the sake of simplicity I've created a codesandbox without vue and vuetify.
I think the best way to solve this, is by make use of css-grid.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-wilson-056e6?file=/index.html)

[image]

Comment: Im trying to make the blue card expand to the bottom of the parent component (it stretches all the way to the bottom but without shooting over like in my example)- without leaving any gaps at the bottom and on the right (but i think this can be achieved with padding/margins?)

Comment: Thanks, btw when I meant to the bottom I was thinking of the child component going to the bottom of the parent. Your first solution is the best one I just need to get rid of the small gaps on the bottom and on the right and that would be what I was looking for. Will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;flex-direction: column`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with Jquery and get the size of your(s) right elements and set it to your vcard.

How guess height ? https://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Better not recommend a jQuery solution when he is already using VueJS. Rather use vanilla JS, especially in 2021. http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#get_height